# Minecraft servers are not being scanned

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to play on a multiplayer for Minecraft on the PC.

All it says in the multiplayer server menu is "Scanning for games on your local network". However, it never finds the server.

How can I make this work?

Comment: **-1** | Although this question is now nicely written thanks to [Peanut](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/188663), you really should use proper English.

Comment: Since you mentioned **Scanning servers on local network**, is your question about making a LAN server, joining a LAN server, or joining any other server?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a server. The "scanning for servers" message is for LAN servers, which are servers hosted on your WiFi/other network.

Pretend we wanted to join the server Mineplex. I'd search for the IP, then enter what ever is there. The IP for Mineplex is `hub.mineplex.com`.

We would go to Multiplayer and click Add Server. Type in a name in the first text box. Then, in the next box, type in the IP. Like I said earlier, the IP is `hub.mineplex.com`. Once you type that in, press Done. Now, you can press the server and click Join to play on it!